# getting random records in many-to-many relationship with namedQuery

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a many-to-many relationship between two objects with a join table. I need to be able to select 5 random children based on Parent and date, excluding some children records. I am stuck. Any ideas?

```
   Parent {
      static hasMany = [children: Child]
    }

    Child {
      Date dob
      static belongsTo = [Parent]
      static hasMany = [parents: Parent]

      static namedQueries {

        randomFiveChildrenBornAfter { parentid, dob, excludeChildren->

          qt 'dob', dob            
          parents {
            eq 'id',parentid
          }
          // not in(excludeChildren) ?? order by rand() ??
        } 
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these literally Parent/Child relationships (as in humans)?  If so, the set of children is likely to be very small and I'd probably just do it in memory rather than through a sql query.

```
parent.children
    .findAll { dob >= fiveYearsAgo }
    .sort { Math.random() }
    .with { it.size() >= 5 ? it.subList(0,5) : it }
```

Comment: Thanks Ted for your response. Unfortunately its not literal and a parent object can have thousands of children so it will get rather expensive doing it in memory... Any way to do it with a query using criterias?

Comment: In that case, you'd have to do it in the database.  Unfortunately, there isn't a database agnostic way of getting a random row.  See this stackoverflow post for details on how to write an HQL criteria that gets random rows with a limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810693/hibernate-criteria-api-get-n-random-rows

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround if you want to use the withCriteria method is this:

```
User.withCriteria{
eq 'name', 'joseph'
sqlRestriction " order by rand()"
}
```

It's important to say that sometime ( depends on the Criteria query created ) it's necessary to add a " 1=1 " in sqlRestriction cause it add an "and" condition in generated query.
So if you have a sqle exception use:

```
sqlRestriction " 1=1 order by rand()"
```