# How Do I Use HQL to SELECT Random Record from Table

Tags: hql

I would like to use HQL to select a random record for a few integration tests.

I've been using SQL Server `ORDER BY newid()`, but HQL parsing likes to raise false alarms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate does not provide a database independent way to do this. You have to do it in two queries.

See [Get random object from SQL database via Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232934/get-random-object-from-sql-database-via-hibernate)